# Masking String with unconfirmed length

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I was trying to mask the string by using STUFF function in SQL.

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(20)='TEST12346',
        @Start    INT = 3,
        @Length   INT = 3;

SELECT @String AS MyString,
       STUFF(@String,  @Start,  @Length, REPLICATE('*', @Length))
```

It only works with strings length longer than 5, else it will return NULL.

How to handle the following case?

**Expected Result**

| MyString | Expected Result | Output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TE | TE | NULL |
| TES | TE* | NULL |
| TEST | TE** | NULL |
| TESTI | TE*** | TE*** |
| TESTIN | TE***N | TE***N |

Comment: MySql features neither `stuff` or `replicate` functions. Perhaps you can point out where these [are documented?](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html)

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. The DBMS I'm using should be Microsoft SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the `iif(LEN(@String) > @Length + 2, @Length, LEN(@String) - 2 )` :

If for example the length of string is 3 THEN `REPLICATE` param should be `LEN(@String) - 2` = 1 not 3

And if length of string is higher than 5 then `REPLICATE` param should be 3

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(20)='TESTII',
        @Start    INT = 3,
        @Length   INT = 3;

SELECT @String AS MyString,
       iif(LEN(@String) >= 3,
         STUFF(@String,  @Start ,  @Length, REPLICATE( '*', iif(LEN(@String) > @Length + 2, @Length, LEN(@String) - 2 ) ) ),
         STUFF(@String,  @Start - 1,  0, REPLICATE( '*', 0  ) )
       )
```

Answer (score 0):

You could build the entire String as if it was long enough for all the '*'-characters. Then wrap the result in a LEFT-function and only return the desired output.

```
SELECT LEFT( SUBSTRING(String, 0, @Start)
           + REPLICATE('*',@Length)
           + SUBSTRING(String, @Start+@Length, LEN(@String))
           , LEN(String)) 
  FROM (VALUES ('TE'), ('TES'), ('TEST'), ('TESTI'), ('TESTIN'), ('TEST12346'))t(String)
```